# Grails data binding

Tags: data-binding, grails, groovy

I'm trying to use [DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToInstance(object, source)](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/DataBindingUtils.html#bindObjectToInstance%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to copy properties from one object to another using this code (which can be run in the Grails console):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils

class Source {

  String foo = 'foo'
  String bar = 'bar'
}

class Target {

  String foo
  String bar
}

def s = new Source()
def t = new Target()

def result = DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToInstance(t, s)

assert t.foo == 'foo'
assert t.bar == 'bar'
```

But the assertions are failing because the properties of `t` are null, why?

Answer (score 3):

The data binder (below) in Grails has only implemented binding for a select subset of object types, namely Maps and Web Requests.  So binding two arbitrary objects isn't implemented.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/DataBindingUtils.java

Comment: That would certainly explain the behaviour I'm seeing though there's nothing in the type signature of the method or JavaDoc comments that makes this clear.